# MKMarkerAnnotationView glyphimage doesn't display

Tags: ios, swift, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to scale a large image to fit in the glyphimage of a subclass of `MKMarkerAnnotationView`:

```
class MyAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    var database = MyDatabase()

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            if let annotation = newValue as? MyAnnotation {
                canShowCallout = true
                markerTintColor = annotation.markerTintColor
                if let pic = annotation.pic {
                    if let image = database.picImage(pic: pic) {
                        print("Found image.")
                        self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                        self.glyphImage = image
                    } else {
                        print("Didn't find image.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it runs, I get the message "Found image." but the only thing displayed is a white rectangle inside the marker annotation.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the type of image you are using along with it's frame? For glyph images, I believe it has to be a template image type for tint color and I think it has size requirements. Docs: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873823-glyphimage?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

you have to hide the rest:

```
self.glyphText = ""
self.glyphTintColor = UIColor.clear
self.markerTintColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to use a template image with a transparent background. If your image does not have a transparent background, the entire image will get the tint color.

See: [Swift 3: UIImage when set to template image and changed tint color does not show image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736520/swift-3-uiimage-when-set-to-template-image-and-changed-tint-color-does-not-show)